# spoj samer08e getting wrong answer

Tags: c++, algorithm

Here is my solution for the spoj problem:

http://www.spoj.com/problems/SAMER08E/

This is my logic:

I check if the given dates are adjacent to each other. If they are, then add the difference of the cost. Else skip.

```
//header files omitted

#define REP(i,n) for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
#define FOR(i,st,end) for(int i=st;i<end;i++)

int monthDates[] = {0,31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};

bool isLeap( int y ){//check if year is leap
 if(y%4 == 0 && y%100 != 0 || y%400 == 0)
     return true;
return false;
}

bool checkAdjacent( int prev[], int curr[] ){//check if the dates are adjacent to each other
if( prev[0] == 31 && prev[1] == 12 && curr[0] == 1 && curr[1] == 1 && (curr[2] - prev[2]) == 1 )//last and first days of the year
    return true;
if( prev[2] == curr[2]){//same year
    if( prev[1] == curr[1]){//same month
        if((curr[0]-prev[0]) == 1)//same adjacent dates
            return true;
    }else if( curr[1] - prev[1] == 1){//adjacent months
        if( isLeap(prev[2]) && prev[1] == 2 && curr[1] == 3 && prev[0] == 29 && curr[0] == 1)//for leap year february
            return true;
        else if( !isLeap(prev[2]) && monthDates[prev[1]] == prev[0] && curr[0] == 1)
            return true;
    }
}
return false;
}


int main(){
int n;
while( scanf("%d", &n) && n){
    int prev[4], curr[4], count = 0;
    ll totalCost = 0;
    REP(i,4)
        scanf("%d", &prev[i]);
    FOR( i, 1, n){
        REP(j,4)
            scanf("%d", &curr[j]);
        if( checkAdjacent( prev, curr) ){
            totalCost += curr[3] - prev[3];
            count++;
        }
        prev[0] = curr[0];
        prev[1] = curr[1];
        prev[2] = curr[2];
        prev[3] = curr[3];
    }
    printf("%d %lld\n", count, totalCost);
}
return 0;
}
```

The program works for the test cases, but i keep getting wrong answer. What is the error?

Comment: Please include all code including macros.

Comment: Mixing ands and ors w/o parentheses (as you do in isLeap) is usually not a good idea.

Comment: I checked the isLeap function. It is working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Since there are two people recording the measurements, it might be possible for the same day to be recorded twice, which could throw off your consumption computation.

Comment: "Some days Martin does it, and some days Isa does."

Comment: Does not explicitly rule out days where both do it.

Comment: In the input it is specified that they will be in strictly increasing order and that no two dates will be the same.

Comment: It says no two CONSUMPTIONS will be the same; it says nothing about adjacent dates.

Answer (score 0):

Your program does not check the condition when the year is leap and the month is not February. Add this condition and you will get AC. I hope this helps.